# Installed python3.10. 'python' points symbolic link. 'python3" does not

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I do have python3.10 working. "python" command works, "python3" command does not, because there is no /usr/bin/python3.

/usr/bin/python is a symbolic link python->/etc/alternatives/python.
python3.10 is in /usr/bin/python.

How to get python3 to point to python3.10? Scripts that call for python3 give the error "/usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: no such file or directory", because, of course, there is no /usr/bin/python3.

I attempted to reinstall python3 but the os knows that python3.10 is already installed.

Thank You
Tom

Comment: Can you add a tag for which OS you're using? From the directories it seems to be some kind of POSIX system, but that's not specific enough. Also, please specify the package manager you've used to install Python, if any.

Comment: Your second paragraph seems self-contradictory.